# Action buttons in ASP.NET Core 2.2 razor view

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Suppose we're redesigning the view below:

[image]

The current code is:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Url)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.BlogId">Edit</a> |
            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.BlogId">Details</a> |
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.BlogId">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Our goal is to remove the `Delete` view that is linked in each row. Instead we would like to have a delete button that deletes the row upon confirmation without leaving the `Index` page (reload is fine).

How would one go about implementing such button? And is there any relevant documentation?

Comment: *have a delete button that deletes the row upon confirmation without leaving the Index page* sounds like you are referring to client side logic, which at it's base is Javascript.  There are a ton of basic frameworks that allow you to build feature rich UI client side experiences.

Comment: Make an ajax call and upon successful completion of that, remove the table row from DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax to issue a delete request so that user can stay during the deletion process. Once the ajax request is successful,you can remove the table row from the UI.

First, add a new attribute to your anchor tag, which you can use for your jQuery selector to wire up the click event.

```
<a asp-action="Delete" ajaxy asp-route-id="@item.BlogId">Delete</a>
```

Here I added an attribute called `ajaxy`

Now we will listen to the `click` event on anchor tags with this `ajaxy` attribute, stop the normal behavior( navigating to the href attribute value URL) and instead make an ajax call. To do the confirmation, you can use `window.confirm` API.

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>

        $(function () {
            $("a[ajaxy]").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                if (window.confirm("Are you sure ?")) {

                    var $this = $(this);
                    var url = $this.attr("href");
                    $.post(url).done(function (res) {
                        $this.closest("tr").fadeOut(300, function (a) {
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("error in ajax call!" + errorThrown);
                    })
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

Assuming your `Delete` action accepts the `Id` parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
{
   // to do : return something     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the extra 'delete' view, you can move the delete code from the delete page tot he index page and use a simple html-form. e.g.

```
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="Delete" class="btn-group-sm" >
    <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a> 
    <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-info">Details</a> 
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Id" />
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this q-Section?')" />
</form>
```

Rename the 'OnPost' function to 'OnPostDelete' and it will work. You can do the same for the 'delete' button on the details page.
Regards Ken.